# group by partition key doesn't work, though it should according to the official documentation

Tags: cqlsh

I set up cassandra version [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.9 | CQL spec 3.4.2 | Native protocol v4] in a docker container.
And I'm using CQLSH.

According to the documentation there is a group by statement for the partition key (and the clustering columns??)
http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#select

But the cqlsh doesn't even recognise the "group by" statement. and generates following message:
SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY clusteringCol;
SyntaxException: line 1:27 no viable alternative at input 'GROUP' (SELECT count(*) from [table] GROUP...)

My table is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE reporting.query (
    shopkey text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    id bigint,
    query text,
    PRIMARY KEY (shopkey, timestamp, id) )  
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC, id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

And this is my query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM query GROUP BY shopkey;
```

Best Regards,
Stefan

Comment: can you please provide the query and table structure

Comment: @deenbandhu 
Thanks for your answere! I added the missing information.

Comment: i think it is a bug in cassandra that is resolved in verison 3.10 see [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10707)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess I'll just wait until version 3.10 is availible as docker image.